Why the sidedrawer is not closing after the approve action is clicked?
import { FileBox } from '@/components/form-fields/AppWorkweekCheckbox/AppFileUploader';
import { FileInfo } from '@/components/form-fields/AppWorkweekCheckbox/AppFileUploader/types';
import Approvers from '@/components/sub-components/Approvers';
import StatusLabel, {
  StatusLabelType,
} from '@/components/sub-components/StatusLabel';
import AppButton from '@/components/templates/AppButton';
import LabelValue from '@/components/templates/LabelValue';
import {
  CACHE_KEY_EMPLOYEE_APPROVE_LEAVE,
  LEAVE_DETAIL_ENDPOINT,
} from '@/constants/my-company/employee-directory';
import useGet from '@/hooks/useGet';
import usePut from '@/hooks/usePut';
import { Domain } from '@/services/api-client';
import useUserStore from '@/store/user.store';
import { fDate } from '@/utils/formatTime';
import { HorizontalRule } from '@mui/icons-material';
import { Box, Grid, Paper, Stack, Typography } from '@mui/material';
import { useQueryClient } from '@tanstack/react-query';
import React, { useCallback, useMemo } from 'react';
import { toast } from 'react-toastify';

interface ILeaveView {
  id: string;
  setTitle: any;
  isApprover?: Boolean;
  setOpen: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<any>>;
   closeDrawer : any
   onApprove:any;
}

interface ILeave {
  leaveId: string;
  dateFrom: string;
  dateTo: string;
  leaveTypeName: string;
  workflowStatus: StatusLabelType;
  workflowId: string;
  requestId: string;
  createdAt: string;
  attachments: FileInfo[];
  log: {
    logId: string;
    agentId: string;
    agentName: string;
    action: 'Approved' | 'Pending' | 'Not Assigned' | 'INPROCESS' | 'Initiated';
    comments: string;
  }[];
}

export default function LeaveView({ id, setTitle, isApprover,setOpen,closeDrawer }: ILeaveView) {
  const { data, error, isLoading } = useGet<ILeave>(LEAVE_DETAIL_ENDPOINT(id), [
    'leave_details' + id,
  ]);
  if (data) {
    setTitle('Request' + '' + '#' + '' + data.requestId);
  }

  const user = useUserStore((state) => state.user);

  const queryClient = useQueryClient();

  const leaveAction = usePut(
    '/request/LeaveRequest/action',
    ['employee', 'leave', 'action'],
    (data) => {
      queryClient.invalidateQueries(['leave_details' + id]);
      queryClient.invalidateQueries(CACHE_KEY_EMPLOYEE_APPROVE_LEAVE);
    }
  );

  const workflowLogId = useMemo(() => {
    return (data as any)?.log.find((l: any) => l.agentId == user?.Employee.id)
      ?.logId;
  }, [data]);

  const canApprove = useMemo(() => {
    return (
      (data as any)?.log.find((l: any) => l.agentId == user?.Employee.id)
        ?.action != 'Approved'
    );
  }, [data]);
  const onAction = useCallback(
    (isApproved: Boolean) => {
      leaveAction.mutate(
        {
          workflowLogId: workflowLogId,
          action: isApproved ? 'APPROVED' : 'REJECTED',
          workflowId: (data as any)?.workflowId,
        },
        {
          onSuccess: () => {
            toast.success(
              isApproved
                ? 'Leave approved successfully'
                : 'Leave rejected successfully'
            );
           
            closeDrawer(false);
          },
          onError: () => {
            toast.error('Failed to perform action');
          },
        }
      );
      if (data) {
        setTitle('#' + (data as any).requestId);
      }
    },
    [data]
  );
  return (
    <Stack justifyContent='space-between' sx={{ height: '100%' }}>
      <Box
        sx={{
          padding: '16px',
        }}
      >
        <Typography
          variant='body1'
          sx={{ color: 'primary.black', fontWeight: 'fontWeightBold' }}
        >
          Leave Details
        </Typography>
      </Box>

      <Box
        sx={{
          padding: '16px',
        }}
      >
        <Grid container>
          <Grid xs={6} sx={{ padding: '0 16px 16px 0' }}>
            <LabelValue label='Request Id' value={'#' + data?.requestId} />
          </Grid>
          <Grid xs={6} sx={{ padding: '0 16px 16px 0' }}>
            <LabelValue
              label='Status'
              value={<StatusLabel label={(data as any)?.workflowStatus} />}
            />
          </Grid>

          {/* <Grid xs={6} sx={{ padding: '0 16px 16px 0' }}>
            <StatusLabel label={data?.workflowStatus} />
          </Grid> */}
          <Grid xs={6} sx={{ padding: '0 16px 16px 0' }}>
            <LabelValue
              label='Request On'
              value={fDate((data as any)?.createdAt.split('T')[0] || '')}
            />
          </Grid>
          <Grid xs={6} sx={{ padding: '0 16px 16px 0' }}>
            <LabelValue
              label='Applied for'
              value={(data as any)?.leaveTypeName}
            />
          </Grid>

          <Grid xs={12} sx={{ padding: '0 16px 16px 0' }}>
            <LabelValue
              label='Leave on'
              value={
                fDate((data as any)?.dateFrom || '') +
                ' - ' +
                fDate((data as any)?.dateTo || '')
              }
            />
          </Grid>

          <Grid xs={12} sx={{ padding: '0 16px 16px 0' }}>
            <LabelValue label='Your Comment' value={''} />
          </Grid>

          {/* included this line by Priti */}

          <Grid xs={12} sx={{ padding: '0 16px 16px 0' }}>
            <LabelValue
              label='Attachment'
              value={
                data &&
                (data as any).attachments &&
                (data as any).attachments.length > 0 ? (
                  (data as any).attachments.map((attachment: any) => (
                    <div
                      key={attachment.filename}
                      style={{
                        display: 'inline-block',
                        margin: '0 10px 10px 0',
                      }}
                    >
                      <span role='img' aria-label='attachment'>
                        
                      </span>{' '}
                      <a
                        href={`${Domain}/uploads/${attachment.filename}`}
                        target='_blank'
                        rel='noopener noreferrer'
                        style={{
                          textDecoration: 'none',
                          color: 'your-desired-color',
                          cursor: 'pointer',
                        }}
                      >
                        {attachment.originalName}
                      </a>
                    </div>
                  ))
                ) : (
                  <div
                    style={{
                      display: 'inline-block',
                      margin: '0 10px 10px 0',
                    }}
                  >
                    <span role='img' aria-label='attachment'>
                      
                    </span>{' '}
                    <a
                      href='#'
                      style={{
                        textDecoration: 'none',
                        color: '#0067FB',
                        fontWeight: 'bold',
                        cursor: 'pointer',
                      }}
                    >
                      View Attachment
                    </a>
                  </div>
                )
              }
            />
          </Grid>
        </Grid>

        <Box sx={{ padding: '16px 0' }}>
          <hr style={{ opacity: 0.4 }}></hr>
        </Box>

        <Typography fontWeight={500}>Approvers</Typography>

        <Stack gap={3} sx={{ marginTop: '24px' }}>
          {data ? (
            (data as any)?.log.map((log: any) => (
              <Approvers
                name={log.agentName}
                label={log.action || 'NOT ASSIGNED'}
                comment={log.comments}
              />
            ))
          ) : (
            <p></p>
          )}
        </Stack>

        <Stack gap={3} sx={{ marginTop: '24px' }}>
          {(data as any)?.attachments?.map((att: any) => (
            <FileBox
              name={att.originalName}
              downloadLink={`${Domain}/uploads/${att.filename}`}
              isDeletable={false}
            />
          ))}
        </Stack>
      </Box>

      {isApprover && (
        <Paper square elevation={2} sx={{ padding: 2 }}>
          <Stack
            flexDirection='row'
            alignItems='center'
            justifyContent='flex-end'
            gap={2}
          >
            <AppButton
              type='submit'
              variant='outlined'
              onClick={() => onAction(false)}
              disabled={isLoading}
            >
              Reject
            </AppButton>
            <AppButton
              type='submit'
              variant='contained'
              onClick={() => onAction(true)}
              disabled={!canApprove || isLoading}
            >
              Approve
            </AppButton>
          </Stack>
        </Paper>
      )}
    </Stack>
  );
}


here i used to declare onClosedrawer which closes the side drawer, but it won't works , i'm passing the props correctly but till i made some mistake in onAction , here i provide also index please some one help me close the side drawer after approve button is clicked
import { Button, Grid, Stack, Typography } from '@mui/material';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import dayjs from 'dayjs';
import customParseFormat from 'dayjs/plugin/customParseFormat';
import AppTextInput from '@/components/form-fields/AppTextInput';
import AppButton from '@/components/templates/AppButton';
import AppDataGrid from '@/components/templates/AppDataGrid';
import AppDrawer from '@/components/templates/AppDrawer';
import AppInfo from '@/components/templates/AppInfo';
import AppLink from '@/components/templates/AppLink';
import AppPaper from '@/components/templates/AppPaper';
import TableSkeleton from '@/components/templates/AppTable/TableSkeleton';
import LeaveForm from './LeaveForm';
import {
  CACHE_KEY_EMPLOYEE_APPROVE_LEAVE,
  CACHE_KEY_EMPLOYEE_LEAVE,
  EMPLOYEE_LEAVE_ENDPOINT,
  EMPLOYEE_LEAVE_PENDING_WITH_ENDPOINT,
} from '@/constants/my-company/employee-directory';
import useGetAll from '@/hooks/useGetAll';
import { Icon } from '@iconify/react';
import { useNavigate, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import LeaveView from './LeaveView';
import { GridColDef, GridRenderCellParams } from '@mui/x-data-grid';
import useUserStore from '@/store/user.store';
import { tabView } from '../HOC/tabView';
import StatusLabel from '@/components/sub-components/StatusLabel';
import { SearchOutlined } from '@mui/icons-material';
import Iconify from '@/components/iconify';
dayjs.extend(customParseFormat);

interface FormData {
  leaveType: any;
  leaveNote: any;
  leaveHistoryWf: any;
  dateFrom: string; // Assuming this is the property representing the start date
  // Add other properties within 'leaveDetails' based on your actual data structure
}

const LeaveListing = ({ isApprover = false, isHistory = false }) => {
  const user = useUserStore((state) => state.user);
  const { id } = useParams();
  const nav = useNavigate();
  const handleSearchChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setSearchTerm(e.target.value);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    // Close the drawer when the id changes
    setImportDrawer(false);
  }, [id]);
  const { data, error, isLoading } = useGetAll<FormData>(
    isApprover
      ? EMPLOYEE_LEAVE_PENDING_WITH_ENDPOINT(user?.Employee.id) +
          (!isHistory ? '/X' : '')
      : EMPLOYEE_LEAVE_ENDPOINT(user?.Employee.id),
    isApprover
      ? CACHE_KEY_EMPLOYEE_APPROVE_LEAVE.concat(
          !isHistory ? ['history'] : ['completed']
        )
      : CACHE_KEY_EMPLOYEE_LEAVE
  );

  const [importDrawer, setImportDrawer] = React.useState<boolean>(false);
  const [addEmpDrawer, setAddEmpDrawer] = React.useState<boolean>(false);
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState('');
  const [viewTitle, setViewTitle] = useState('');
  const [openSideMenu, setOpenSideMenu] = useState<boolean>(false);
  // added the filtering for search
  const filteredData = data
    ? data.filter((row) => {
        const searchText = searchTerm.toLowerCase();

        const requestIdMatch = row?.leaveHistoryWf?.requestId
          ?.toLowerCase()
          .includes(searchText);
        const leaveTypeMatch = row?.leaveType
          ?.toLowerCase()
          .includes(searchText);
        const leaveNoteMatch = row?.leaveNote
          ?.toLowerCase()
          .includes(searchText);
        const statusMatch = row?.leaveHistoryWf?.status
          ?.toLowerCase()
          .includes(searchText);

        const dateFrom = row?.dateFrom;
        const isDateFromValid = dateFrom && typeof dateFrom === 'string';

        const dateMatch =
          isDateFromValid &&
          dayjs(dateFrom)
            .format('MMM DD YYYY')
            .toLowerCase()
            .includes(searchText);

        return (
          requestIdMatch ||
          leaveTypeMatch ||
          leaveNoteMatch ||
          statusMatch ||
          dateMatch
        );
      })
    : [];

  React.useEffect(() => {
    // Update filteredData whenever the data or searchTerm changes
    if (data) {
      const filtered = data.filter((row) => {
        const dateFrom = row?.dateFrom;
        const isDateFromValid = dateFrom && typeof dateFrom === 'string';

        setSearchTerm(searchTerm); // Update the searchTerm state variable
      });
    }
  }, [data, searchTerm]);
  const isWorkflowPending = isApprover && !isHistory;
  let columns: GridColDef[] = [
    {
      field: 'id',
      flex: 1,
      headerName: 'Request Id',
      renderCell: (params: GridRenderCellParams) => {
        const { value, row }: { value?: string; row: any } = params;
        return <AppInfo mainText={'#' + row?.leaveHistoryWf?.requestId} />;
      },
    },

    {
      field: 'leaveType',
      flex: 1,
      headerName: 'Leave Type',
      renderCell: (params: GridRenderCellParams) => {
        const { value, row }: { value?: string; row: any } = params;
        return (
          <AppInfo
            mainText={row?.leaveHistoryLeave?.leaveName}
            subText={`Requested on ${dayjs(row.createdAt).format(
              'MMM DD YYYY'
            )}`}
          />
        );
      },
    },

    {
      field: 'leaveDate',
      flex: 2,
      headerName: 'Leave Date',
      renderCell: (params: GridRenderCellParams) => {
        const { value, row }: { value?: string; row: any } = params;
        const start = dayjs(row.dateFrom);
        const to = dayjs(row.dateTo);
        const diff = (row?.dateTo && Math.abs(start.diff(to, 'day'))) + 1 || 1;
        return (
          <AppInfo
            mainText={
              <>
                <Icon width={16} height={16} icon={'ion:calendar-outline'} />
                {` ${start.format('MMM DD YYYY')} ${
                  row?.dateTo && `- ${to.format('MMM DD YYYY')}`
                }`}{' '}
              </>
            }
            subText={`${diff} ${diff > 1 ? 'days' : 'day'} Leave`}
          />
        );
      },
    },
    {
      field: 'leaveNote',
      flex: 1.2,
      headerName: 'Status',
      renderCell: (params: GridRenderCellParams) => {
        const { value, row }: { value?: string; row: any } = params;
        return <StatusLabel label={row.leaveHistoryWf?.status} />;
      },
    },
    {
      field: 'action',
      flex: 1,
      headerName: 'Action',
      renderCell: (params: GridRenderCellParams) => {
        const { row }: { row: any } = params;
        return (
          <Stack
            sx={{ width: '70px' }}
            direction='row'
            alignItems='center'
            justifyContent='space-between'
          >
            <AppLink path={row.id}>View</AppLink>
          </Stack>
        );
      },
    },
  ];
  if (isWorkflowPending) {
    // If it's a workflow pending tab, remove the 'Action Token' column
    columns = columns.filter((column) => column.field !== 'leaveNote');
  }
  const handleCloseDrawer = () => {
    setImportDrawer(false);
  };
  if (error) return <p>error</p>;

  return (
    <AppPaper>
      <Grid container spacing={2}>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <Stack
            padding={2}
            direction='row'
            sx={{ width: '100%' }}
            justifyContent='space-between'
            alignItems='center'
          >
            <Typography variant='subtitle1' fontWeight='fontWeightBold'>
              {isApprover ? 'Leave Approvals' : 'Leave Requests'}
            </Typography>
            <Stack direction='row' spacing={2}>
              <AppTextInput
                startIcon={<SearchOutlined />}
                placeholder='Search by Request Id, date...'
                value={searchTerm}
                onChange={handleSearchChange}
              ></AppTextInput>

              {!isApprover && (
                // <AppButton
                //   variant='contained'
                //   onClick={() => setImportDrawer(true)}
                // >
                //   Apply Leave
                // </AppButton>
                <Button
                  variant='contained'
                  onClick={() => setImportDrawer(true)}
                  startIcon={<Iconify icon='ic:round-add' width={20} />}
                >
                  Apply Leave
                </Button>
              )}

              <AppDrawer
                header='New Leave Request'
                open={importDrawer}
                setOpen={setImportDrawer}
              >
                <LeaveForm closeDrawer={setImportDrawer} />
              </AppDrawer>
            </Stack>
          </Stack>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12} sx={{ overflow: 'auto' }}>
          {data && !isLoading ? (
            <AppDataGrid
              columns={columns}
              rows={filteredData}
              rowHeight={75}
              getRowId={(row: any) => row.id}
            />
          ) : (
            <TableSkeleton columns={columns} />
          )}
        </Grid>
      </Grid>

      <AppDrawer
        header={viewTitle || 'View Leave'}
        open={!!id}
        setOpen={(state: boolean) =>
          !state
            ? isApprover
              ? nav('/approval/leave')
              : nav('/ess/leave')
            : null
        }
      >
        {id && (
          <LeaveView setTitle={setViewTitle} id={id} isApprover={isApprover} setOpen={setOpenSideMenu} closeDrawer={setImportDrawer} onApprove={handleCloseDrawer} />
        )}
      </AppDrawer>
    </AppPaper>
  );
};

export default tabView(LeaveListing);


it is index page which calls leave view component in here also i try somany methods but nothings works , i set drawer to false but it keep till keeps the drawer open, please some one give me the solution
